# How do I print out somethng at the start of an output window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Just wondering if there's something to print out at the start of an output windwo instead at the end of it with END, an example:

```
outputWindow.insert(END, calc)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `outrputWindow`? Is it a `Text` widget, and `Entry` widget, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
outputWindow.insert(0, stuff_to_be_printed_out_here)
```

What you're giving as the first parameter of the insert method is actually the index number of the character stored in `Entry()`. Each character is an item here.

Comment: welcome @Nomadck. Are you a beginner in tkinter world?